# PrimeNG tree table - how to stop propagation upward?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

I am using PrimeNG treeTable (`p-treeTable`) in Angular 10 with checkbox selectors (`p-treeTableCheckbox`) as per their example
[scroll down to the Checkbox Selection](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/treetable/selection)

In this implementation if a user expands a node and un-selects a sub item, the parent node is also un-selected. This is undesired behaviour in our scenarios. I would like the parent to remain selected even if all the sub nodes were un-selected. But if the user selects/un-selects a parent node, it is still valid to select/un-select all the child nodes as it does.

For example, in their example, expand the first node "Applications", expand the next node "Angular" then uncheck a child node like "mobile.app" => both Angular and Applications parents become unchecked.

So is it possible to have the parent nodes remain unchanged when a child node is changed?

My table is:

```
<p-treeTable [value]="allUsers" selectionMode="checkbox" [(selection)]="selectedNodes">
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" id="{{rowNode.node.Email}}">
                    </p-treeTableToggler>
                    <p-treeTableCheckbox [value]="rowNode"></p-treeTableCheckbox>
                    <span>{{rowNode.node.data.Name}}</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>
```

There doesn't appear to be any behavioural properties on the `p-treeTableCheckbox` that would effect this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a property called `[propagateSelectionUp]="false"` that can be applied and works exactly as I wanted....the trouble is that it doesn't exist on the `p-treeTable` component, only on the `p-tree` component.
So the solution was to move to the `p-tree` component and implement the `[propagateSelectionUp]="false"` property.

results:

```
<p-tree [value]="allUsers" selectionMode="checkbox" [(selection)]="selectedNodes" [propagateSelectionUp]="false">
   ...
```

Comment: The property [propagateSelectionUp] seems gone in the new primeNg? Do you know how to stop the propagation now?